# convert a text file to csv using shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting, can anyone give me shell script for the condition below

My Input:

```
id | name | values
----+------+--------
  1 |  abc |      2
  1 |  abc |      3
  1 |  abc |      4
  1 |  abc |      5
  1 |  abc |      6
  1 |  abc |      7
```

Expected Output:

```
1,abc,2
"
"
1 million records
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=, 'NF==3 && NR>1{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/, "", $1); print}' file
1,abc,2
1,abc,3
1,abc,4
1,abc,5
1,abc,6
1,abc,7
```

Comment: if i have 10 columns where can i change

Comment: Just change `NF==3` to `NF==10`